# Cast to string failed for value Error when submitting the form, using FileBase from React to convert the image

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have an error when i try to post this schema data into Form.js. Mongoose schema looks like this:

```
const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    message: String,
    creator: String,
    tags: [String],
    selectedFile: String,
    likeCount: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date()
    },
});
```

Logic for creating post is like this:

```
export const createPost = async (req, res) => {
    const post = req.body;

    const newPost = new PostMessage(post);

    try {
        await newPost.save();

        res.status(201).json(newPost);
    } catch(error){
        res.status(409).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}
```

I'm uploading image as String and I'm converting image using base64 from React like this-

```
import FileBase from 'react-file-base64';
<div className={classes.fileInput}><FileBase type="file" multiple="false" onDone={(base64) => setPostData({ ...postData, selectedFile: base64})}/></div>
```

When I try to submit form, I get error like -
**{"message":"PostMessage validation failed: selectedFile: Cast to string failed for value**

Comment: Isn't that a typo ? Voting for closing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, I was missing {} brackets aroung hte base64 after the onDone. so it should be like:

`<div className={classes.fileInput}><FileBase type="file" multiple={false} onDone={({ base64 }) => setPostData({ ...postData, selectedFile: base64 })} /></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You missed the curly braces around `base64` in `onDone={({ base64 })`.

yes you must add {} to base64 I tested it and it works !!!!